# How can I toggle a filter?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I toggle a filter correctly?

I need a function that will turn my page into inverted black and white. When I run the function again, it should return it to its original colors.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function ToggleAccessibility() {
    if (!blackAndWhite) {
        (function () {
            var body = document.body;
            body.style['filter'] = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1 invert(100%))';
            if (!body.style['filter']) {
                body.style['-webkit-filter'] = 'grayscale(1) invert(100%)';
                body.style['filter'] = 'grayscale(1) invert(100%)';
            }
            blackAndWhite = true;
        }());
    }
    else {
        (function () {
            var body = document.body;
            body.style['filter'] = 'none';
            if (!body.style['filter']) {
                body.style['-webkit-filter'] = 'none';
                body.style['filter'] = 'none';
            }
            blackAndWhite = false;
        }());
    }
}
```

The first time the function runs, it correctly works to make the page inverted black and white. The second time, it correctly returns the screen to normal.

But after that it doesn't do anything. Setting the filter to `'none'` seems to prevent any further changes to the page for some reason. I'm not sure what's the correct way to go about this.

Comment: Instead of adding style and making them none, try writing css using class. You can write your color css to one class and toggle it on body tag with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.invert {
    filter: grayscale(1) invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) invert(100%);
}

<body class="invert"> <!-- Toggle invert class using javascript -->
```